# How can I show data from a db table that I'm already using else where in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I've been going through the tutorials on rubyonrails.org so I have a model pulling data from the Articles table from my postgres db. I have my view displaying this table of records perfectly fine.  However I'd like to know how I then add just the last Article record on the home page for instance.  Do I 'query' the same Articles application record, or do I simply create an entirely new model, which doesn't seem that efficient as a site grows.

Do I generate complete new model such as `rails generate model LastArticle`?  I see that it looks like I can use `article = Article.last` or should this be `lastarticle = Lastrticle.last` and would I put this in the Model or a Controller?

Only been looking at RoR (coming from more of a php mysql background) for a few days so sorry if this is a jumbled question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Models can be used anywhere in the rails application.  In your home view controller you could do

```
@last_article = Article.last
```

And then reference `@last_article` in your home view.

You can even retrieve the record as part of the view...

```
<% last_article = Article.last %>
```

And then reference `last_article` in the same view.

Comment: Ok, so would I have something like:

home view controller:

`class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def show
    @last_article = Article.last
  end  
end`

And in my home view:

`<h2>Latest Article</h2>

<% @last_article = Article.last %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= article.title %></td>
    <td><%= article.text %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Read', article_path(article) %></td>
  </tr>
<%end%>`

Comment: Well,no... first, you don't need to do `@last_article = Article.last` in both places, if you're doing it in the index method then you don't need to do it in the view.  Second, the object is `@last_article` so you can't do `<%= article.text %>` because `article` is not defined anywhere... do instead `<%= @last_article.text %>`  Hope that's clearer.

Comment: And of course, everywhere else where you reference `article` needs to change.. e.g. `<%= link_to 'Read', article_path(@last_article) %>`

Comment: Cheers @SteveTurczyn I'll try that.

Comment: Boom - Worked a charm.